# Retrieve and then post data using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to improve my PHP/AJAX skills and I faced a problem.

I have these JS scripts:

First one - retrieves all relevant posts from the database, just 10 posts, then after reaching some scroll point it gets another 10 posts and so on:

```
  var start = 0;
  var limit = 10;
  var reachedMax = false;

  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
      get_posts();
  });

  function get_posts() {  
    if (reachedMax)
        return;

    $.ajax({
       url: '/includes/fetch_home_posts_2.php',
       method: 'GET',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: {
           getData: 1,
           start: start,
           limit: limit
       },
       success: function(response) {
            if (response == "reachedMax")
                reachedMax = true;
            else {
                start += limit;
                $("#result").append(response.fetched_posts);
            }
        }
    });
  }

get_posts();
```

Piece of the PHP looks like this:

```
while (fetching posts from DB) {
  $post_output .=  "<div>here is the post header, content, ect.</div>";
}
$response_array = array(
   'fetched_posts' => $post_output
);
echo json_encode($response_array);
```

All this works as it should (I hope so).

Then I have the second JS script - it adds comment for a certain post into the DB:

```
$("form.comment_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/insert_comment_into_database.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        complete: function () {
          //alert("Comment has been added!");
        },
        success: function (data) {
          //location.reload();
          alert("Comment has been added!");
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
  });
```

It does what it is supposed to do - gets posts, inserts comment into DB correctly.

The problem I'm facing is, that everytime I post a comment for any post, the whole page reloads (which is okay), but it takes me to the whole beginning of the page. What I'm trying to say is, that when I am in the middle of page (for example) and I post a comment, it can reload (so the new comment will appear on the page) but I need to stay at the exact same place.

I hope you can understand me, English is not my native language.

Comment: Instead of reloading the page, just return the comment in the ajax response and add it to the page in the correct place using JS. That would probably be a much smoother user experience than reloading the page.

Comment: Your English is fine :) Please also post the code that doesn't work, with the comments HTML section